# TFS SQL Query to Find Merges Between Branches

Tags: sql

I would like to be able to query TFS to look for specific check-ins.    The database Tfs_Warehouse has a table called DimChangeset in it which has a good bit of data around specific changesets.   However I’d like to limit the data by only returning information that has been between a specific branch.

The [DimChangeset] table in Tfs_Warehouse shows all check-ins, but doesn't say where what they were from or too.

Is there any way via a SQL query to check for all merges between one code branch and another?  Not across projects, just between two specific branches.

The database that TFS uses has things like the ParentPath, but I can't see exactly how to find a destination path or ID?  I figure there must be something based on the fact that it knows about it in work items.

Answer (score 0):

You have to query the FactCodeChurn table; see reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620645.aspx)

Comment: Can you expand on your answer any more?